# How to Query all opportunities ids from account

Tags: apex, soql, community, salesforce1-app

I write a sample query to fetch account Ids from cases of a particular record type.Then i wrote another sample query parent to child relationship to fetch opportunity ids from accounts.

My sample code

```
List<Case> c=new List<Case>();
c=[Select Id,accountId from case where RecordTypeId = '01290000000sF3L'];
List<Id> accountIds= new List<Id>();
List<Account> accounts=new List<Account>();
List<Opportunity> opps=new List<Opportunity>();
for(Case cl:c) 
{
accountIds.add(cl.accountId);
}
accounts=[Select Id,name,(select Id,name from opportunities) from account       
where Id in:accountIds];
System.debug('Data in accounts '+accounts);
```

But my issue is how to get opportunity id from above Soql accounts means how to add those opportunity id's to the list.

```
for(Account ao:accounts) {
//How to fetch Opportunity ids from above account list.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most efficient:

```
Set<Id> childIds = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(ao.Opportunities).keySet();
```

You can also loop through them:

```
for (Opportunity child : ao.Opportunities)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One quick addition to Himanshu's post -  add [] to accounts in the query.  This will make the query to fetch 200 records per iteration than 1 record per iteration.  You can find this at [Trailhead data modelling](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_modeling).

However I would suggest not to put SOQL in a for loop. Query it outside as in your code.

```
for(Account[] ao:[Select Id,name,(select Id,name from opportunities) from account       
where Id in:accountIds]) {
   for(Opportunity opp : ao.opportunities)
   {
       //Other Operation you want to perform with every opportunity
       System.debug(opp.Id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access relationship data using relationship name so your code can be modified in following way

```
List<Case> c=new List<Case>();
c=[Select Id,accountId from case where RecordTypeId = '01290000000sF3L'];
List<Id> accountIds= new List<Id>();
List<Opportunity> opps=new List<Opportunity>();
for(Case cl:c) 
{
accountIds.add(cl.accountId);
}

System.debug('Data in accounts '+accounts);

for(Account ao:[Select Id,name,(select Id,name from opportunities) from account       
where Id in:accountIds]) {
   for(Opportunity opp : ao.opportunities)
   {
       //Other Operation you want to perform with every opportunity
       System.debug(opp.Id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add in your code:

```
for(Account ao:accounts) {
    opps.add(ao.opportunities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how big your org is, but this should get what you're looking for. I would run the actual query part here in workbench first to see how intensive it is and maybe put a filter on the account query.

```
Set<Id> opptIds = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([
    SELECT Id 
    FROM   Opportunity 
    WHERE  AccountId IN (SELECT Id 
                         FROM   Account) 
        AND AccountId IN (SELECT AccountId 
                          FROM   Case 
                          WHERE  RecordTypeId = '01290000000sF3L') 
]).keyset();
```