# SOQL to pull child record id from associated parent

Tags: soql

I want child record id with associated parent record id (e.g
parent id=`a8u540000004CWVAA3`). I need all the associated child record ids given that parent Id

```
SELECT Name,id, (SELECT ID FROM CHILD OBJECT__R)  FROM parent object__c  where id IN ('a8u540000004CWVAA3','a8u540000004CWBBC4')
```

Comment: select name, id from contact where accountid in ('a8u540000004CWVAA3','a8u540000004CWBBC4')
select name, id from contact where accountid in (select id from account where name like 'Alice%')

Comment: Even though the objects are different, this question is almost identical to [How to Query all opportunities ids from account](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126240/how-to-query-all-opportunities-ids-from-account)

Answer (score 1):

Take the id's of parent object records in a list

`List<parentobject__c> pic = new List<parentobject__c>();`

`pic.add(/*place your ID here*/);`

Use the query Like below...

`[SELECT Name,id, (SELECT ID FROM CHILDOBJECTS__R) FROM parentobject__c where id IN: pic]`

Note: you have to place the plural of child object name appending with __r.

If your child object name is `Student__c`, then you have to place `Students__r` while using the subqueries.

Hope this might helps...

Comment: Hi  please see below ,gives me an error plz assist                                                                                                                                  list<Quote_Project__c>pic=new
list<Quote_Project__c>();
pic.add('a8uE0000000gItP');

[SELECT Name,id, (SELECT ID FROM cell_Block__R) FROM Quote_Project__c where id IN: pic]

Comment: You have to give cell_blocks__r as I mention in my answer NOTE. Plural must be given for custom object subquery

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be correct.

If you want to list down only the Id fields from child then use this as below:

```
SELECT ID FROM CHILD_OBJECT_c WHERE parentId in ('a8u540000004CWVAA3','a8u540000004CWBBC4')
```

You can refer this link [relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)

Comment: I tried above query doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i tried all the above queries doesn't work please assist

listpic=new list(); pic.add('a8uE0000000gItP'); 
[SELECT Name,id, (SELECT ID FROM cell_Block__R) FROM Quote_Project__c where id IN: pic]

Error=Unknown error parsing query

Comment: ahh!! Are you trying this in Query Editor in developer console?  Query editor only takes in direct SELECT statements only.   Where are your trying the code?